# Multiple ClickOnce applications associated with the same file type

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have multiple .Net applications that read the same file type, but when deployed with ClickOnce, the file association in Windows is made to "ClickOnce Application Deployment Support Library", which is what actually launches the program.

But once the first .Net application is installed on the workstation, subsequent applications can't be selected in the "Open With" menu, and "ClickOnce Application Deployment Support Library" won't give the user a choice, either.

How can I associate multiple ClickOnce-published applications to the same file type so the user can pick between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. AFAIK, ClickOnce only supports one file association. My guess is that it always uses the last one the user installed.

I'm checking with the product team to make sure, and will comment back after I get an answer.